# Can a RhinoMock mock hold property values?

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have been stuck on this for a day or two, I have recently started using RhinoMocks (v3.5)and I have setup a test. A stub web service that returns a List collection and a class that calls it, and a mock object with a property i expect to be set as a result of the call to the web service. My code is like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void Call_WebService_list_populated()
    {

        IData stService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IData>();
        IDefault mockView = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDefault>();

        DefaultPresenter presenter = new DefaultPresenter(mockView);
        presenter.StService = stService;
        mockView.Stub(x => x.RequestingUser).Return("test");
        List<string> testList = new List<string> { new string() };
        stService.Stub(x => x.GetList("test")).Return(testList);

        presenter.LoadList();
        Assert.AreEqual(testList,mockView.List);
    }
```

In the LoadList function it just assigns the List property of mockView the list returned from the webservice.  I can get the test to work using this line:
mockView.AssertWasCalled(a => a.StoryListing = testList);
but i expected that the mock object would hold state and i could check the property directly.  Am i doing something wrong or is this just the way you have to use rhino mocks ie: the mock object cant hold state as when i do the assert.areequal nunit says the mockView.List property is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, mocks don't handle get/set properties (not sure why.  There's a way to change it but I can't remember offhand).  You can generate your mockView as a stub (`MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDefault>()`) -- and stubs support property behavior.

Comment: Strange that they dont handle properties but i suppose i could use a stub its just semantically a stub wouldnt be right for the purpose i'm using it for, maybe like you say theres a way to change it though. Thanks!